# Mimicking Special JavaScript Callback in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, callback

I am having trouble particular with this type of callback implementation in C++.  In the below code, I would like to store a callback into "OnRenderingComplete". However, I'm having trouble remembering the "ad" variable and "callback" parameters of "adOnRenderingComplete".
How is this implemented in C++?

```
var adOnRenderingComplete = function(ad, callback) {

};

var setAdPlaybackCallbacks = function(ad, callback) {

    OnRenderingComplete = function() { adOnRenderingComplete.call(this, ad, callback); };
};
```

In JavaScript, it seems that this is possible since there can be an embedded function storing the parameters of "ad" and "callback"... but I am not sure how this would be done in C++. I' would ultimately like to call OnRenderingComplete(), with it "remembering" the parameters "ad" and "callback".

I am having a hard time. I can't seem to figure this out. The only thing close that I can think of is to define a class within the function and pass the function of that class to OnRenderingComplete. But even so, the below is wrong and does not compile.

```
void testCall(void (*callback)())
{
    callback();
}

void test1()
{
    class blah
    {
    public:
        int a;
        int b;
        void c()
        {
            cout << "a * b = " << a*b << endl;
        };
    };

    blah ex;
    ex.a = 5;
    ex.b = 3;

    void(*OnRenderingComplete)() = ex.c;
    testCall(OnRenderingComplete);    // I would like to have this print the value of a*b
}
```

Essentially, I am attempting to capture "ex.c" inside the callback variable "OnRenderingComplete". But, at the same time, I'd like to capture the value of ex.a and ex.b so that ex.c can be called while "remembering" the data for "a" and "b". After making the call "testCall(OnRenderingComplete)", I would like the function at the top for testCall() to be able to print the value of a*b.

Comment: You can use lambdas, if you're compiling in C++11.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Synxis. Is it possible to do without C++11?

Comment: Yes, but that will be more complicated, depending on whether you can use boost or not.

Comment: Ah I see... any help will be appreciated. Do you know how it would be done without boost / with boost?

Comment: can you create a minimal working example and show what you've tried in C++? With some context it would be quite easy to answer your concrete question.

Comment: Here you are, I posted an answer. What you want is not clear, so I just showed how to create and use callbacks.

Comment: Synxis, thank you for your answer! I edited my original post to be a bit more clear. Basically, at the bottom of my post, I'd like testCall(OnRenderingComplete); to be able to print the value of a*b by itself, without passing in any parameters.

Comment: Answer updated (not only at the end). What you want is still unclear, though...

Comment: Hi synxis, I've updated my original post by adding text at the bottom

Comment: Ok then, either you pass `blah` (or its fields) as parameter to `boost::bind`, or you use a lambda (and so you do not need to pass `blah` as a parameter). See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several solutions (click on the titles for a live example):

**[C++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0f7017bae1a48b4)**:

```
#include <functional>

struct MyClass
{
    typedef std::function<void (int, bool)> CallbackType;
    typedef std::function<void (int, float, bool)> AnotherCallbackType;
    CallbackType callback;

    void setCallback(AnotherCallbackType c, float param)
    {
        callback = [&](int a, bool b) { c(a, param, b); };
        // Calling the callback:
        callback(42, false);
        // With lambdas, it is almost like in Javascript,
        // you can embed all parameters you want. ex:
        std::function<void()> func = [&](){ c(2, param, true); };
        func(); // will call c(2, param, true);
    }
};
```

**[C++03, with Boost](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/295ef869a4e2e33e)**:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

struct MyClass
{
    typedef boost::function<void (int, bool)> CallbackType;
    typedef boost::function<void (int, float, bool)> AnotherCallbackType;
    CallbackType callback;

    void setCallback(AnotherCallbackType c, float param)
    {
        callback = boost::bind(c, _1, param, _2);
        // Calling the callback:
        callback(42, false);
        // This will call: c(42, param, false)
        // The 'param' float parameter has been retained.
        // It is possible to retain all parameters when binding, ex:
        boost::function<void()> func = boost::bind(c, 2, param, true);
        func(); // will call c(2, param, true);
    }
};
```

**[C++03, without Boost](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f56c87f4a5240f10)**:

```
struct MyClass
{
    typedef void (MyClass::* CallbackType)(int, float);
    CallbackType callback;

    void onRenderCallback(int param1, float param2) {}
    void setCallback(CallbackType c)
    {
        callback = c;
        // Calling the callback:
        (this->*callback)(42, 3.14f);
        // Note that it is possible to embed the parameters
        // but that will need to create a class, basically it means you will reimplement Boost.Bind...
    }
};
```

Now, back to your code:

```
void(*OnRenderingComplete)() = ex.c;
```

For pointer to function, I seriously advise you to use typedefs:

```
typedef void (*OnRenderingCompleteType)();
OnRenderingCompleteType callback = ...;
```

Then, `ex.c` has the following type: `void (blah::*)()`. Note the `blah::*`, it is because this is a pointer-to-member-function, *not* a pointer-to-function (member functions are special functions). This is the reason why the assignment does not compile.

Comment: So for instance, an example of what I'd like to achieve is the following:

OnRenderingCometeType callback = (this->*callback)(42, 3.14f);   I would like to be able to call "callback()" and have it remember the parameters 42 and 3.14f.

Comment: Do you have access to C++11 ? Post your compiler as a comment (or in the question). The syntax `(this->*func)(args)` is for pointer-to-member-function, that's the lowest level thing about callbacks. I put that in the answer for the completeness of it, but I advise you to use C++11 (or at least Boost).

Comment: Thanks! I will use C++11 for this and use the std::bind method! This is great. Thanks for your help.